# django - debugging django in PyCharm

Tags: django, debugging, server, pycharm

I have a server in django which return **500 Error Code** to my POST request from my mobile android app.

When I access it in the browser it works fine..

I don't really know how to debug\see any error messages in PyCharm. all I see is this, in the console window:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 24, 2015 - 17:09:12
Django version 1.8.1, using settings 'RidesBackend.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[24/May/2015 17:10:01]"POST /users/register HTTP/1.1" 500 66235
[24/May/2015 17:11:10]"POST /users/register HTTP/1.1" 500 66235
```

From what I read 500 is **INTERNAL SERVER ERROR** - 
so the error is in the server side, but I can't possibly know what is is without seeing error messagess or something...

I guess my question is where can I see **error messages/LogCat/anything that reports errors with description** in **Pycharm** for a django project? or debug it somehow?*

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are a lot of links out there in the web about debuging in PyCharm, pycharm docs for example: [debug basics](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/starting-the-debugger-session.html), [debug console](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/using-debug-console.html).

Comment: If you're using django then you might want to try the [django debug toolbar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar). It helped me (but it slows things down so don't use it in production).

Comment: If you see this without knowing more, set DEBUG to True temporarily and dump the stack trace + error here...